# What do you call a person who is pulling water from a well right now?

Tags: single-word-requests

The text is old scripture, at one point it talks of a person who is pulling water from a well. It doesn't necessarily have to be their job. How do you refer to the person who is pulling water out of a well right now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112175/discussion-on-question-by-hossein-what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-pulling-water).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the best word that was suggested in comments (now deleted) is "the man who is drawing water" or "water drawer".

The biblical citation (Joshua 9:21) is:

> [“hewers of wood and **drawers of water**”](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095934458)

This sounds a little archaic, but would seem to suit the context, and there is no modern equivalent in Western culture. The biblical meaning is more general, indicating a menial labourer.

Comment: Well done for shaming those who ignore the explicit SE injunction not to answer questions in comments. However to construct a good answer you need to cite sources in support of your answer. An Internet search (the biblical “drawers of water” should get you a response). If you find this difficult for any reason, I am happy to assist.

Comment: I would love your help, thanks.

Comment: Done. I used the square brackets with the "linked text/normal brackets with the link" style to add a link. No spaces before the normal brackets.

Comment: @David That is great. Thank you very much.